# How can I call controller function with foreach loop?

Tags: php, yii2

I have the following within my foreach loop within my index file:

```
foreach($dataProvider->getModels() as $post) { 
    $status = $this->status($post->id);
    var_dump($status);
}
```

However get the following error, I can confirm the function I am trying to call works because in the single view file:

```
Calling unknown method: yii\web\View::status()
```

**UPDATE**

See this link for more detail [Yii2 Forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/63169-way-to-call-controller-method-in-view-yii2/)

But the below works add context

```
$this->context->functionname();
```

Comment: I am assuming that the status method is in the same class as the foreach code block you posted?

Comment: @LarryLane yes the method basically checks if the user is already logged in and then uses the data sent in this case post->id to check if its in the table as I say it works fine when I use in my view its called in the controller rather than the view file but this carnt be done for index as its not a single record but looping through.

Comment: Sounds like a scope issue of some sort. Is the method your are calling private? is the class loaded inside of your controller before it outputs to the view?

Comment: please show the code where you define the status function..

Comment: and the code where you use the foreach.. in the qay you posted is not possible understand you goal ..

Comment: @scaisEdge I have now added my controller function

Comment: And you want use this function where? in a view?

Comment: @scaisEdge i am wanting to use the function in a view which is where my foreach loop is if that possible?

Comment: I have postet a brief explanation.. i hope is useful and you can find the better solution . otherwise comment me.

Answer (score 0):

Is better place this kind of function in model and then or in an helper class..

because $this in view is related to /* @var $this yii\web\View */ and not to the controller.. if you place the function in a model or in an helper class ..

you can easily access declaring the correct

use path\ClassName

and if a model creating a new one.
If are general function the helper class  solution is better..

Comment: I have updated my answer with a solution but within the linked forum someone said it was bad practice, do you know what they mean.why? they aid use a ViewiHelper?

Comment: Good practice or Bad practice.. well the in a view a check for a status over a dataprovider provided by the same controller where you place the function is not a good way .. you have already the data where you have the function. then peform the check in the controllerand send the data already controlled

Comment: If the function is a general function provide an helper ar if is strictly related to the model ad to the model. is not a context problem..i think

Comment: Anyway I don't dislike the use of $this->context->functionname(); however  in a good programming flow and design.